# Ensure that a directory reflects a specified Git commit

Tags: ruby, git

I have a method that looks like the method below, and I can't help but shake the feeling that it can be improved. It doesn't really "read" well, and it seems like `checkout` could be called only once, somehow.

```
def ensure_correctness
  if exist?
    unless correct_version?
      delete!
      checkout
    end
  else
    checkout
  end
end

def checkout
  run_command(['git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', url, path])
end

def exist?
  Dir.exist?(path)
end

def delete!
  FileUtils.rm_rf(path)
end

def correct_version?
  commit_sha_short == desired_commit_sha_short
end
```

The best I could come up with is moving the code from failing `correct_version?` to a new method (which probably isn't a terrible idea, but I wonder if I can do better).

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: What happened to `operation_1`? I agree with the above comment though, the more context you can add the better, really.

Comment: @SimonForsberg operation_1 was purely for notification, I'm not sure it was terribly useful, so I eliminated it to hopefully make the question easier to understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have two conditions and two (or three including the removed notification) actions. Make a truth-table and see which actions should run when, and then you might easier see what the best way to structure your logic is.

Comment: Just to be clear: My suggestion about a truth-table was a suggestion for the future for similar problems, not meant as a direct answer to your question. If you undelete your question it will be reopened now. Thanks for listening to our feedback about your question.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Holy cow! It turns out it did pay to have the real methods in place for an ideal solution. It would still be nice if there were a generic solution to the originally posted problem, it seems to me that there is a more elegant way to express that logic lurking just below the surface... Anyway, thanks to you and 200_success for pushing me to improve the question as I think it ended up resulting in a better solution. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two calls to `checkout` look well to me.  They are simple method calls to self with no arguments, and I can easily see that both calls are the same.  You avoid making two identical calls to `run_command(['git', 'clone', ...])`.

The "something really obvious" might be a `return`:

```
def ensure_correctness
  if exist?
    return if correct_version?
    delete!
  end
  checkout
end
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for addressing the more abstract problem! I believe you are correct about the "something really obvious", but I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same thing in a different arrangement without the return... If I can't think of any, I'm going to mark this as accepted, as it most closely satisfies my original curiosity.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which of the three solutions do you consider to be more idiomatic/readable?

Comment: Your `correct_version? || delete! && checkout` confused me because of operator precedence. I first thought of Unix shell (sh), where `||` and `&&` have same precedence. Then I remembered that Ruby does `&&` before `||`. The code might be more readable to people who don't know sh.

Answer (score 1):

While I envisioned just moving the instructions in `ensure_correctness` around a little, to find an efficient solution to a pattern a see repeated with some frequency, it turns out it was better to rearrange everything a little. I think the final solution is more attractive, even if it does potentially call `delete!` unnecessarily (it doesn't matter).

```
def ensure_correctness
  unless correct_version?
    delete!
    checkout
  end
end

def checkout
  run_command(['git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', url, path])
end

def exist?
  Dir.exist?(path)
end

def delete!
  FileUtils.rm_rf(path)
end

def correct_version?
  exist? && commit_sha_short == desired_commit_sha_short
end
```

Comment: I think ultimately this solution works better for the application than the [accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181814/62096), both in terms of readability and robustness. The adjustment has the side-effect of making the `correct_version` method technically more correct, which could be useful if consumed from elsewhere. I really appreciate everyone that took a look at this question - thanks!

Comment: Personally I would prefer parenthesis around `delete! && checkout`, but that might just be because I am not used to Ruby's operator precedence and that I prefer to avoid combining `&&` and `||` on the same line.

Comment: That "less confusing" way is wrong, should use `unless` instead of `if`. And you rely on `FileUtils.rm_rf` returning something "true" but the documentation doesn't specify any return value. Is that safe? (Also, if someone changed `delete!` so it returns something "false", that would break it as well. And since `delete!` isn't documented at all, one might feel free to make such a change, not knowing that it breaks something.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann, you're right, good catch! Updated answer, thanks.